# python: os.path.exists() unicode exception

Tags: python, xml, unicode

In my python program, I use `untangle` for parsing XML file:

```
from untangle import parse

parse(xml)
```

The XML is encoded in utf-8 and contains non-ASCII characters. In my program, this is causing trouble. When the xml string is passed to `untangle`, it tries to be smart and automatically check if it's a file name first. So it calls

```
os.path.exists(xml)
```

And it looks like the `os` module tries to convert it back to ascii and caused the following exception:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 169-172: ordinal not in range(128)
```

At the top of this file, I'm doing this as a trick that supposedly would work around this:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work.

I don't know what else can go wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a bit odd that untangle doesn’t offer direct functions for this.

The simplest solution would be to copy the relevant implementation of [`untangle.parse`](https://github.com/stchris/untangle/blob/master/untangle.py#L151) to parse files:

```
def parse_text (text):
    parser = untangle.make_parser()
    sax_handler = untangle.Handler()
    parser.setContentHandler(sax_handler)
    parser.parse(StringIO(content))
    return sax_handler.root
```

Answer (score 0):

Does decoding help for your case like below? Reloading sys and setting utf-8 as default is not a good habit.

```
from untangle import parse
xml=isinstance(xml, str) and xml.decode("utf-8") or xml
parse(xml)
```